# Work with SVN in Android studio 1.3

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I have local android studio project,i imported it into remote folder at one of subversion,repositories. Import is done but when i try to explore the remot folder that contains the project,it stuck 'loading' and it doesn't finish. If i try to checout the project from remote folder to my local disk. Checking out process it taks long time and stuck without finish.
Dears,i need the correct setps to work with android studio svn. 
Thank you.

Comment: the project you are trying to import is created from the same android studio version or with different version? i think that that android studio 1.0 and 1.3.2 have different folder structure.

Comment: The project was built in eclipse and i converted it to android studio. Import process to subversion is done perfectly,but  after import i can't browse it in svn repositories and my team members also can't check it out. It stuck checking out when they try to check it out